# Facebook is unable to retrieve my iPhone Store ID from the App Store

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, app-store-connect, facebook-oauth

I can't get Facebook to recognize that my app is live. I have never had this problem before and the app has been live in the US for over 12 hours. I put in the App ID from iTunes Connect and it throws the following error.

"We were unable to retrieve your iPhone Store ID from the iTunes App Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later."

I tried putting in a different App ID from one of my other apps and it works just fine. For some reason it won't recognize this one..

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve it? I have the same thing.